# permanently disable hyper-v in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have to use VMware systems which cannot run under Hyper-V.
I know I can turn off Hyper-V in the windows feature list. However this requires a reboot.
After the reboot, Hyper-V is not active and my VMware clients can run - BUT:
the feature is enabled again so that after the next reboot it is there again.

How can I *permanently* disable Hyper-V in Windows 10?

Comment: Try this command in power shell and check.  Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my part I can now answer my question. At my workplace we have centrally managed PCs and it has been a company or group policy to activate Hyper-V at login time. Now I am on an exception list and Hyper-V remains deactivated.

Comment: Any other local suggestions for blocking the group policy activation of hyper v?

Comment: ok, this is an interesting cause. Which GPO can be set to force Hyper-V setup?

Answer (score 3):

It is not normal, that Hyper-V gets readded again after a reboot. I have no idea ho to prevent this, but I have an answer to stop Hyper-V from getting working.

Open a command prompt as admin and run this command:

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

After a reboot, Hyper-V is still installed but the Hypervisor is no longer running.

Now you can use VMware without any issues.

If you need Hyper-V again, run this command from a cmd, started as admin:

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Comment: I tried it: `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off` but it didn't work; Hyper-V was on after reboot

Comment: have you tried to start Hyper-V? It should be off. This is also explained from Microsoft Employees: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx

Comment: Tried again: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off`, which printed: 
`The operation completed successfully.` Yet, after reboot Hyper-V was on again. The blog refers to Windows 8, so I guess something changed in Windows 10 (although I have this problem only on 1 out of 2 Windows 10 dev PCs)

Comment: Activating the respective Windows Feature also alters the `hypervisorlaunchtype` flag. So this won't help unless you identify what keeps activating Hyper-V.

Comment: @DanielB you should not change Hyper-V in UI. Only change this BCD setting to switch between Hyper-V and other VM tools like Vmware or VirtualBox

Comment: @magicandre1981 I never said to touch the GUI. For him, the whole Hyper-V Feature activates by itself. That would of course also negate any boot option changes.

Comment: @DanielB but when hyper-v is activated and you later hange the BCD setting, nothing gets changed itself.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to be. Windows Features aren't supposed to activate by themselves either. So I guess instead of fighting the symptoms, he should find the original issue.

Comment: @DanielB my guess, during disabling something wents wrong and he sees "failure: rolling back changes" during boot. But the BCD command works. I just tested it. After a reboot, I can no lomger run a VM because the Hypervisor is off. Now he an use other tools

Answer (score 0):

On GPO:

Administrative template -> device guard -> Turn on virtualization based securitu = set to enabled

And you have a VMware issue :/

Comment: It's a long time ago. It has been resolved by asking our central management to cancel this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I tried running the Docker. It gave me the error message that you need to disable hyper-V. Now I got it fixed. Let me share with you the steps I did. I hope everyone is aware that for installing Docker you need to have either Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise Edition or the Educational version.

1. Mine is the Windows 10 Pro edition but since I was facing the same issue, I uninstalled the Docker Desktop from my Control Panel.
2. Rebooted my machine and installed the Docker Toolbox.exe(Normally this is used for older versions of Windows OS)
3. Installed Docker Toolbox, by checking the additional components VirtualBox and Git(You can check these to be installed along with the Docker if you don't have them installed on your machine. Because if you skip this, error msg may pop up on the screen saying that some files are missing.)
   4.Now opened the Docker Toolbox terminal.Now it showed the msg that VT/AMD has to be enabled in the bios
   5.Since I have a Dell laptop, tried pressing F2 continuously at the time of reboot and found that VT-I/O option has a check mark on it.
   6.Now exited from the BIOS setup screen, waited for the windows to start up normally and again tried opening the Docker terminal
4. This time it worked perfectly with no issues.It ran the pre-checks and I got the message that says "Docker is up and running"